# Weight samples if incorrect guessed in binary cross entropy

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, keras, weighted

Is there a way in `keras` or `tensorflow` to give samples an extra weight if they are incorrectly classified only. Ie. a combination of class weight and sample weight but only apply the sample weight for one of the outcomes in a binary class?

Comment: Do you want these weights to be computed at each epoch separately or to be fixed for whole training process?

Comment: Whatever works. As I understand they are normally updated after each batch?

Comment: It is possible. Provide us with the loss you use and the way you want to compute weights - so we could provide you with implementation.

Comment: I’m just using the binary cross entropy function of keras.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it's possible. Below you may find an example of how to add additional weight on *true positives* , *false positives* , *true negatives*, etc:

```
def reweight(y_true, y_pred, tp_weight=0.2, tn_weight=0.2, fp_weight=1.2, fn_weight=1.2):
    # Get predictions
    y_pred_classes = K.greater_equal(y_pred, 0.5)
    y_pred_classes_float = K.cast(y_pred_classes, K.floatx())

    # Get misclassified examples
    wrongly_classified = K.not_equal(y_true, y_pred_classes_float)
    wrongly_classified_float = K.cast(wrongly_classified, K.floatx())

    # Get correctly classified examples
    correctly_classified = K.equal(y_true, y_pred_classes_float)
    correctly_classified_float = K.cast(wrongly_classified, K.floatx())

    # Get tp, fp, tn, fn
    tp = correctly_classified_float * y_true
    tn = correctly_classified_float * (1 - y_true)
    fp = wrongly_classified_float * y_true
    fn = wrongly_classified_float * (1 - y_true)

    # Get weights
    weight_tensor = tp_weight * tp + fp_weight * fp + tn_weight * tn + fn_weight * fn

    loss = K.binary_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred)
    weighted_loss = loss * weight_tensor
    return weighted_loss
```

Comment: very interesting, but how can I pass in the vector with the individual weights that need to be applied as punishment for each sample if incorrectly classified?

Comment: But this function computes indices of misclassified examples - so you don't need to pass one. Do you want to manually choose examples you want to punish more?

Comment: No, just the ones that are incorrectly classified need to be punished more. I.e. there is a payoff that is either +1 (correctly classified), or it is -x (incorrectly classified). I described the problem slightly differently here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/327763/custom-loss-function-with-weights-and-asymmetric-payoff. I assume that the weight vector would need to be passed into the loss function.

Comment: Is it correct that tn = .. *(1-y_true). Shouln'd it rather be ... * K.equal(y_true, False)? Similar to how I describe it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48744092/weighted-loss-function-for-payoff-maximization

Comment: This is fine. Target is `float32` so one could use this heuristic. Btw. False is equal to 0.

Comment: I'm not worried about the data type, but your suggestion of 1-y_true is not equal to y_true==False (which i think is what we should use in the term to define true negatives). Would you not agree?

Comment: 1 - y_true is equivalent to y_true == False

Comment: This answer is most likely incorrect as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48771961/weighting-true-positives-vs-true-negatives/48833827#48833827